# How to delete text selection with range in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code, textselection

I have a csv that looks wrong on certain lines so I want to delete lines manually in line range `1` to `281387` using Visual Studio Code as Text Editor.

[image: vs code]

I've tried using the cursor and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> from line `281387` to line `1` but it takes a very long time. Is there a quick way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- cursor on line 281837 or start of 281838
- and then key `Ctrl+Shift+Home`

Answer (score 1):

The quick way is to not use vscode ;)

Unhelpful cheekiness aside, use vim or emacs to make quick work of this. Assuming you haven't installed emacs, vim is likely already on your machine. If you're windows, go install neovim.

1. Open vim to that file (`vim /path/to/that/file`) or `nvim` if you are using neovim
2. Press the escape button (gets you into normal mode)
3. hit `gg` (gets your cursor to the top of the file)
4. Now type `281387dd` and hit `enter` (this runs the delete lines `dd` command however many times you asked it to)
5. If it looks right, type `:wq` to save the file and quit vim (`:q!` to just quit without saving)

Comment: Ok, sir. But my OS is Windows.

Comment: Well, that's your first problem! Jokes aside, give neovim an install. (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim) and you should be good to go after that. 

As an aside, given that it's a `.csv`, excel would also be pretty ok at that.

Answer (score 0):

An extension like [Select Line Range](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StephanCasas.select-line-range) allows to quickly select any range of lines in your document, including from the cursor to any line.  Then just `delete`.

Comment: That extension doesn't work in my vs code.